# React Redux update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am trying to do a simple thing : I have a reducer with 3 inputs and I want to change the value of the input clicked that is to say **change the value of an attribute in the store**. How do I do it ?

I am using **React and Redux**.

Here my reducer-inputs.js :

```
export default function (){
    return[
      {
        "name":"InputOne",
        "deviceType":"Input",
        "value":"42",
        "description":"This is the first Input"
      },
      {
        "name":"InputTwo",
        "deviceType":"Input",
        "value":"21",
        "description":"This is the second Input"
      }, 
      {
        "name":"InputThree",
        "deviceType":"Input",
        "value":"13",
        "description":"This is the third Input"
      }          
    ]
}
```

Then, I put the reducer in my store.

My component element where the click event is :

```
<td className="sendButton" onClick={() => this.props.changeButtonValue(this.props.activeDevice.name,this.refs.buttonConfig.value)}> Send </td>
```

I created an action :

```
export const changeInputValue = (name,val) => {

        console.log(name + ":" + val);
    return {
        type: "INPUT_CHANGE",
        payload: {name,val}
    }

};
```

**And here, I am striving to change the value of the input...**

```
export default function (state={},action){

    switch(action.type){

        case "INPUT_CHANGE":
            console.log(action.payload); 
            // shows the name of the input and the new value wanted
            console.log(action.payload.name);
            console.log(state)
            // shows the element in the reducer I feel like changing
            return {
                ...state,
                value: action.payload.val
                // some code Here ....

            }

        break;
        default:
            return state;


    }

    return state;
}
```

Here my Input field :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import {changeInputValue} from '../Actions/index';

class DeviceConfig extends Component {

    render() {
        switch(this.props.activeDevice.deviceType){

            case "Input":
                return (
                    <div>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td className="selected_DeviceName"> {this.props.activeDevice.name} </td>
                                    <td> <input type="number" ref="inputConfig" defaultValue="" /> </td>
                                    <td className="sendButton" onClick={() => this.props.changeInputValue(this.props.activeDevice.name,this.refs.inputConfig.value)}> Send </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>                  
                );

            default:
                return (
                    <p> Select a Device </p>
                );

        }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
            activeDevice:state.activeDevice,
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({changeInputValue: changeInputValue}, dispatch)
}

// Link between store and container
export default connect(mapStateToProps,matchDispatchToProps)(DeviceConfig);
```

Here a picture of my interface to describe my problem : [image]
Any Idea ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Does it triggers properly "INPUT_CHANGE" in your reducer ? It looks like it is nicely changed in your store (use redux devtool to know how is your state) edit : can we see your input field ?

Comment: I put my input field code. In fact, i don't know if the code in the return section of the case INPUT_CHANGE is the right one or not but i have no errors and the input value does not change in the page when i click on the send button...

Comment: Isnt it just that you look for activeDevice.name while you set activeDevice.value in your reducer ?

Comment: Ok, action.payload.value doesnt exist, you're setting it to val by doing         payload: {name,val}. But name should works properly. Can you do a fiddle ? I think its simple mistake but I can't point it out

Comment: I changed to val but still no errors and no changes in the input value... I have just made a picture of the interface :)

Comment: Do you use reduxDevtool extension on chrome ? It may tells you if your state is nicely formatted

Comment: I don't use it, I am going to install it so. I put a picture to describe the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149808/discussion-between-nevosis-and-e-b).